# Trouble with understanding test cases for HackerRank problem on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, bash

As part of a training course, I have to complete this simple question on HackerRank, but I'm having trouble with passing the test cases. Basically, all I have to do is use the HTTPS module in NodeJS to fetch a page from wikipedia and write the response into an HTML file. The program pretty much works as specified but the 'test cases' keep failing. From what I understand, all the tests do is run a few commands to check for certain keywords and filenames, but no matter what I try, I keep getting a score of 0.

Here are the tests, in a .test.sh file:

```
SCORE=0
PASS=0
fail=0
TOTAL_TESTS=1

TEST_1=$((( $(ls | grep -e "App" -e "Nodejs.html" |wc -l)>=2 )) && (( $(grep "443" App.js |wc -l)>=1 )) | wc -l)
if [ $TEST_1 -eq 1 ]
then PASS=$((PASS + 1))
fi;

echo "Total testcases: 1"
echo "Total testcase passed: $PASS"
echo "Total testcase fail: $fail"
SCORE=$(($PASS*100 / $TOTAL_TESTS))
echo "You have scored:$SCORE%"
```

I believe the left-hand part of the test expression is checking for the App.js and Nodejs.html files in the directory, both of which are there. The right-hand side is looking for the number 443 (which is the port number to use for the request) in the App.js file. I don't know linux commands very well so correct me if I'm wrong.

My Node.js code is contained in App.js:

```
const https = require("https");

const options = {
  hostname: "en.wikipedia.org",
  port: "443",
  path: "/wiki/Nodejs",
  method: "GET",
};

let writeableStream = fs.createWriteStream("Nodejs.html", {
  encoding: "utf-8",
});

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  res.pipe(writeableStream);

  res.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});

req.end();
```

The code executes and I should've hit all of the criteria, but I still get a 0.

Comment: learn to deconstruct complex expression into the compoent parts and be sure each element is working. So does `ls | grep -e "App" -e "Nodejs.html"` return the two taget words? If not, what about just `ls | grep -e "App"` (and then just 1-e "nodejs.htmo"`)? Go for the smallest component o the expression and then add more element until you see where it is failingl Good luck.

Comment: And of course `ls | grep -e "App" -e "Nodejs.html"` assumes your running this script from the correct directory. It is likely you could reduce this to just `ls  *App*  *Nodejs.html*` but there are too many other could-be's here, best to get the basics working as mentioned above. Good luck.